# What is the difference between Candidature and Candidacy

Tags: word-meaning

I found this [link](https://wikidiff.com/candidature/candidacy), but it was not very helpful.
Is candidature a more archaic version of candidacy or do they have any difference in meaning/context?

Comment: Oxford Languages treats them as synonyms.

Comment: [Google N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=candidature%2C+candidacy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccandidature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidacy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccandidature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidacy%3B%2Cc0) shows candidature was more popular in much of the 19th century, but since the 1890s, candidacy is more common. I can't think of a difference, but there may be specific cases where one is preferred.

Comment: Switching n-grams to British suggests that candidacy only overtook candidature in Britain in c. 1980.  So some dialect difference.  Wikidiff is always completely useless in every respect.